# Why when a type do implementing an interface there is a difference in behavior?

Tags: go

Who can tell (or link where to read), why when a type do implementing an interface
there is a difference in behavior (depending on how to transfer the recipient)?
Here so it works:

```
type GetNamer interface {
  GetName()
}

type Person struct {
  PersonName string
}

func (p Person) GetName() {
  fmt.Println(p.PersonName)
}

type Data []GetNamer

var d = Data{
    Person{"Vasya"},
  }
```

But, if I pass the recipient by the link: **(p *Person)**
I get an error that types (Person and GetNamer) do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you change the receiver signature to `(p *Person)` it means that `*Person` implements the interface, not `Person`, so your "Data" array must be changed to match.

That is, you must change the signature of the interface method *and* the contents of the "d" variable to contain Person pointers and it should work, since `&Person{...}` is a `*Person` which is a GetNamer:

```
func (p *Person) GetName() {
  // ...
}

var d = Data{
  &Person{"Vasya"},
}
```